# JButton to do different actions depending on the last button pressed

Tags: java, jbutton, conditional-statements, listeners

JButton1 
do an action

JButton2
do an action

JButton3

do action A if JButton1 is the last button pressed.

do action B if JButton2 is the last button pressed.

What conditions should I put in the listeners of JButton3?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `enum` or just an int to store the value of the last button clicked for all buttons but not button3.

Put an if statement in button3's click event

Comment: That sounds good, thanks!